# org.codehaus.classworlds.NoSuchRealmException: plexus.core

Tags: jakarta-ee, maven-2, tomcat7, maven-tomcat-plugin

I am trying to use an Apache Maven Tomcat plugin for Tomcat 7,
so I added the following dependency to the [POM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven#Project_Object_Model) file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
    <artifactId>plexus-classworlds</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
</dependency>
```

**Plugin configuration**:

```
<plugin>

    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <configuration>
        <path>/${project.build.finalName}</path>
    </configuration>

</plugin>
```

**Repositories**:

```
<repositories>

    <repository>
        <id>people.apache.snapshots</id>
        <url>http://people.apache.org/repo/m2-snapshot-repository</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>

</repositories>

<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>apache.snapshots</id>
        <name>Apache Snapshots</name>
        <url>http://people.apache.org/repo/m2-snapshot-repository</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

**Maven OPTS**:

```
-Xmx512m -Xms256m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m
```

but when running the application with mvn tomcat7:run i am getting following exception:

```
org.codehaus.classworlds.NoSuchRealmException: plexus.core
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.ClassWorld.getRealm(ClassWorld.java:128)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:434)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
```

Why? Do I have something wrong in configuration, or I am missing something?

Answer (score 5):

When I got this error, I was trying to mvn package a *maven:grails* app on Jenkins. The weird part was that I had it working on my old [Hudson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hudson_%28software%29) [CI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) server. All I had to do to fix the problem was add the following JVM options to the configuration for the package command:

```
-Xmx2048m -Xms512m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
```

[image: Jenkins job config → Build → Invoke top-level Maven targets → Advanced...]

Click "Advanced..."

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I experienced the same issues myself when using this. It seems that when the plexus code runs, it does not handle OutOfMemory Exceptions well.

If you increase the allocated amount of memory to the JVM during the build, you will find that the error goes away. The problem is the PermSize for the stack. Refer to this link: [Get started with java JVM memory](http://avricot.com/blog/index.php?post/2010/05/03/Get-started-with-java-JVM-memory-%28heap,-stack,-xss-xms-xmx-xmn...%29) for details on how to configure your JVM Memory.

Try using settings as such:

- -Xmn256m
- -Xms512m
- -Xmx1536m
- -Xss1m
- -XX:PermSize=512m
- -XX:MaxPermSize=768m

Answer (score 0):

Run by console:

```
mvn clean install -DXms512m -DXmx2048m -DXX:MaxPermSize=1024m
```

Or set environment parameter:

```
export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xms512m -Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m"
```

Using system environment file: Add MAVEN_OPTS="-Xms512m -Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m" in "/etc/environment" file.

And next run:

```
mvn clean install
```

Use in Eclipse, adding to MVN Arguments following:

```
-DXms512m -DXmx2048m -DXX:MaxPermSize=1024m
```

(It works to me)